# How do I reference PHP functions?

Tags: php, function, static

I'm making a plugin system. I have a class `extensionmanager` that takes the name of a plugin as a constructor parameter. Long story short, this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$this->parsedata = function($data) { 
    $this->extension::parsedata($data); 
};
```

`$this-extension` is a string with the name of the plugin. I have run static functions in the exact way shown in this example before. Now I'm getting the error `unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` on that second line (I've heard it roughly translates to "unexpected double colon")

Could anyone help me understand why?

---

Before the above example I tried to run something like this

```
$this->parsedata = &$this->extension::parsedata;
```

Hence the question title. The top example I thought was closer to working so I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) may give you a solution. Somewhere in the examples you have this code :

```
<?php

namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test() {
        print "Hello world!\n";
    }
}

call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
call_user_func(array(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo', 'test')); // As of PHP 5.3.0

?>
```

I think you can easily adapt this to call your static function. For example something like :

```
call_user_func(array($this->extension, 'parseData'), $data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do that:

```
$self = $this;
$this->parsedata = function($data) use ($self) { 
    {$self->extension}::parsedata($data); 
};
```

Yet, I would suggest to avoid static functions. After all, whoever is going to use your extension manager will need to conform to some interface. Why not take advantage of abstract methods or interfaces to make the user conform to your interface?